# Firefox 3: Enable AJAX to localhost from outside domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, localhost, xss

I am running a HTTP server on my development machine. I have a website, on some web server on the Internet. How can I get Firefox to allow communication from this website to `localhost` temporarily while I develop?
Thanks,
Isaac Waller

Comment: This isn't programming related. This is a config issue.

Comment: it's not code related, but it is programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach I use in this situation is to insert a hosts-file entry mapping localhost to a subdomain of the target internet site.

Comment: I tried this but you are not allowed to AJAX to a subdomain (?)

Comment: by editing document.domain (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain), you can relax the single-origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local proxy (such as [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)) to route the AJAX requests to the service on your LocalHost.

Comment: You can trivially write some FiddlerScript to do this.  See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp for the "Retarget requests" sample.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to do it you can set up your web server so it temporarily serves the content with an access-control header. But for your situation it would be best to use a proxy. See this:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-in-firefox-3